# Masonry like placement

Tags: css

I got a category page to integrate, kinda special.

Here is the image :

[image]

As you can see, there is posts. There is X posts.

So as first, I would've manage the positions of, for example, the 6 first example (with nth-child) and then I imagined using Javascript to determine between -200 and 200 a number to randomly add a transform: translateY or a margin-top to post.

Here is what I've made so far :

```
<div class="category-page__content">
   <div class="category-page__content__header">
       <h1>Newsroom</h1>
       <p>blablabla</p>
   </div>
   <div class="category-page__content__posts">
     <Post>
     <Post>
     <Post>
     <Post>
     ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the global idea of the HTML.

Then I did that in CSS (SCSS here) :

```
.category-page__content__posts {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 60px;
  transform: translateY(-350px);
  > * {
   &:nth-child(2) {
     margin-top: 200px;
   }
   &:nth-child(3) {
     margin-top: 770px;
   }
   &:nth-child(4) {
     margin-top: 415px;
   }
 }
}
```

But I feel like it's a little messy.

If you have any better idea I would love to hear it.

And as I said, for others posts that would come after the 6 elements (4 here), I imagined placing it with Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Column direction Flexbox is one solution. Remove all the `nth-child` selector rules in your CSS and change the wrapper CSS to this. Achieves the effect with enough posts.

```
.category-page__content__posts { 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 100vh; // whatever max-height you want
  width: 100%;
}
```